# Where can I get airport diagrams of non-towered airports?

Tags: usa, aeronautical-charts, non-towered-airport, chart-supplement

I'm trying to find a couple of airport diagrams for right now: [X26](http://airnav.com/airport/X26) and [X59](http://airnav.com/airport/X59).

Neither of them are listed in the [Chart Supplement](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/) or on the FAA site.
All I could get were those shabby diagrams presented by Airnav and Skyvector and sorts, and Google Earth images, both of which are not current. (The runway numbers are different from what are actually designated (painted) and used.)

Does anyone have a better idea about where to find the airport diagrams?

Plus, what the heck is the order of those airport diagrams listed in the Chart Supplement?! I couldn't find any rules.

Comment: What *are* the current runway numbers for X26? I'm finding a diagram in the d-CS just fine...

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject Looks like they're 10/28 and 5/23 like in Carlos post

Answer (score 3):

Many non-towered airports have diagrams in the Chart Supplement, and there is an [airport diagram for X26](http://aeronav.faa.gov/afd/27apr2017/se_149_27APR2017.pdf) but [not for X59](http://aeronav.faa.gov/afd/27apr2017/se_158_27APR2017.pdf). The difference appears to be that X26 has instrument approaches but X59 doesn't. It looks to me like the airport diagrams are considered [part of the terminal procedures](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/).

But I have to say that the FAA is as clear as mud on this. The [airport diagrams legend](http://aeronav.faa.gov/content/aeronav/online/pdf_files/legendAD.pdf) says:

> selected towered airport diagrams have been published in the Airport
>   Diagram section of the A/FD

But obviously that's completely wrong, because a) many non-towered airport diagrams are in there, and b) the A/FD doesn't exist any more.

By inspection, it looks to me like airports without an instrument approach have no airport diagram (X59, X25, 2RR) and ones with an approach do have one (X26, X07, AVO). But I only spent a few minutes looking, so I may well be completely wrong on this.

As for your question about the order of diagrams, [the legend says](http://aeronav.faa.gov/content/aeronav/online/pdf_files/legendAD.pdf):

> Diagrams will be listed alphabetically by associated city and airport
>   name

Comment: No objection to your insight about the "selected airports" so far. Thanks!

Comment: And thanks for pointing that out as well. I was _skippy_ through that header in the Chart Supplement. That was, however, my initial thought that it seems like they're in the order of those names of cities or of airports, and then I just gave up on it when I found that there are SOME exceptions in that order. Seems like these ones had their airport names changed recently but still some others are not in the order by the name of the city.

To sum it up for the order: most of them are sorted out by city name, but some are by airport name and the latter ones' names' have been changed.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone have a better idea about where to find the airport diagrams?

For U.S. airports, consider using the [AOPA Airport Directory](https://www.aopa.org/destinations/). It's searchable by anyone without charge. I just checked, searching using X26 as the input string and then X59, and it has airport diagrams for both.

Answer (score 1):

Try contacting the airport manager at those airports for this or more info:

X59: 321-952-4590
X26: 772-228-7013

ForeFlight makes a basic airport diagram for X26 and for X59.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Interesting that they have one for X59 -- X26 has one in the Chart Supplement, but X59 doesn't for some odd reason

Comment: Thank you!! I was curious in general regarding those non-towered airports but anyways.. I guess I have to get the ForeFlight first. Or try contacting them.